# Running Android cardboard activity as service

Tags: android, google-cardboard

Any idea on how I would go about running the android [CardboardActivity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/CardboardActivity)as a service, and still be able to perform vr/openGl intensive task?

Comment: Can you share the code you have written so far ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer for one special service getting permission to access the screen. Further investigation may lead to a generalized answer.

The android live wallpaper service does this. The issue of course is with the permission to bind to the screen frame buffer, which live wall paper services are given.

`android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"`

So if you implement your app with a live wallpaper service, and manage to set it as your app background, you will also have an app that doubles as a wallpaper. Keep in mind that wallpapers are very constrained in what they can do, but the OP did not specify any other requirements.